# How to get result from database based on date insered and assign it to input field using PHP and jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So i build an app on cordova .The app must save, edit and delete records.I  managed to save data ,but now must edit insered data based to date insered in database.User is registered and logged by an email and password.There are two datatables, one with registered users,and another with events . They are linked by email (foreign key) .So based to a date picker an date is selected on form( ) and another input () where user insert what they wish(the event),and this are saved in database. And now i want to loop first database when a date is selected,to see if it is or not insered an event to that date,for that user.And if is insered to append the event of database in  ,if not user can insert a new event.

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVTU0.png)

```
<html>

        <form>
            <label>Scegli data:</label>
            <input id="giorno" type="date" data-type="date" name="date_input"/>

        </form>

        <label class="item-input">
            <span class="input-label">La mia giornata</span>
            <textarea id="event" rows="10" cols="30" placeholder="Come e stata la tua giornata?"></textarea>
        </label>


        <ul class="list list-inset">
            <li class="item" style="color:#D26F6F;">
                Email
                <p class="item-note" id="email1"></p>
                <br>
                <a href="change-password.html">Cambia parola</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</html>
```

> js part:

```
   var email = localStorage.email;

   $("#giorno").change(function () {
        var giorno = $("#giorno").val();
        var dataString = "giorno=" + giorno + "&email=" + email + "&found=";
        var event=$("#event").val();
        if (event != '') {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://----/auth.php',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: "json",
                data: dataString,
                crossDomain: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.error == '') {
                        $(".msg").html("");
                        $("#event").html(data.events.event);
                    } else {
                        $("table").hide();
                        $(".msg").html("No record found!");
                    }
                }
            });
        }   return false;
    });
```

auth.php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['found']))
{
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $rawdate = htmlentities($_POST['giorno']);
  $giorno = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rawdate));
  $data=array();
  $q=mysqli_query($con,"select event from `events` where `email`='$email' and `created_at`='giorno'");
  if($q!=0 )
  {
     while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($q)){
        $data[]=$row;
     }
     echo json_encode($data);

  }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact question/problem?

Comment: is that the code seems don`t get the result from database to be insered to input ( <textarea id="event">

Comment: So your php echoes out an array of rows.  Where are data.error and data.events coming from?

Comment: Now i check prepared statements. But you can give me an idea about my problems? Using this prepared statements. Tnx you

Answer (score 1):

```
var email = localStorage.email;

$("#giorno").change(function () {
    var giorno = $("#giorno").val();
    var dataString = "giorno=" + giorno + "&email=" + email + "&found=";
    var event=$("#event").val();
    if (event != '') {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://----/auth.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            data: dataString,
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.error == '') {
                    $(".msg").html("");
                    $("#event").html('');
                    for(var i=0; i<data.events.lenth;i++)
                    {
                        $("#event").append(data.events[i]['event']);
                    }
                } else {
                    $("table").hide();
                    $(".msg").html("No record found!");
                }
            }
        });
    }   return false;
});
```

Comment: i will try it now to see if it change something.tnx